# Re-jiggering the date to show up correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby, datetime, date

Right now my application is spitting out:

`Now Showing: 2012-01-07 – 2012-06-07`

Which is pulled from a jQuery date picker that outputs the format in the same way. I want it to show up as "July 1, 2012 – July 6, 2012"

I've tried using the .strftime("%b %d %y") method but that hasn't helped fix this.

In my application, a user selects a date range from the main page and that date is pushed into the model as `report[params][:start_date]` and `report[params][:end_date]`

Those dates are pushed into a mySQL query which is rendered in a Javascript Highchart on a `reports/id` page.

It's a standard Rails app without anything fancy. My goal is to have the date show up as Month, Date, Year and this jQuery date selector is formatting it as Year-Day-Month. Not sure if I should change the date formatting in my `application.js` file or what I should do to resolve this.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong format for `.strftime`. It should be

```
your_date_object.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

jQuery UI's Datepicker has a [`dateFormat`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) option.

```
$('your_selector').datepicker({
  // your options
  dateFormat: "MM d, yy"
});
```

There's also a [`$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, settings )`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) function to help with date formatting *(should you choose to reformat the value of the input when the page loads via jQuery too)*.

Comment: Thanks @Deefour. I'm a bit confused where I can change the date in Jquery. This is a standard Rails application, not sure where I'd put this code.

Comment: I can't really help with that since you haven't provided any code or context to your problem.